# Verifying HTML table data in WebDriver

Tags: html, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone plz explain me how to verify the data in HTML table using WebDriver?

HTML is like below..I need to verify the values xyz, abcd, 1234, 5678 on the webpage

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>abcd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234</td>
<td>5678</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance!!
mra.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind your excerpt from the question:

> I need to verify the values xyz, abcd, 1234, 5678 on the webpage

I suggest you try to identify these values  using locators and then asserting/verifying the same.

In this example I have used XPath ( a bit verbose for clarity)as the locating strategy.Hope this helps.

```
    try {
    assertEquals("xyz", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[1]/td[1]")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
try {
    assertEquals("abcd", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[1]/td[2]")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
try {
    assertEquals("1234", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[2]/td[1]")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
try {
    assertEquals("5678", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[2]/td[2]")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will depend on whether that table will only ever contain 2 rows and 2 columns. Will the rows and columns always exist in the same order? If not then the xcode example provider before will work, if not you might need to be a bit more creative.

One approach that I've used before to crawl through a table is similar to this.

Define a WebElement that represents your table.

```
WebElement yourTable = driver.findElement(By.tagname("table"));
```

Next create a List of WebElements that represent each row in the table.

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = yourTable.findElements(By.tagname("tr");
```

Finally, you can loop through the rows of the table until you find the data you are looking for.

```
for(int i=0; i<tableRows.size(); i++){
    WebElement row  = tableRows.get(i);
    now do whatever you want with your WebElement that represents a single row of the table;
    }
```

Hope this helps.